# Java determine screen instance when monitor is added

Tags: java, screen, detection, monitor

When a new monitor is added to a PC or a laptop that's already running a JRE instance, we find that the monitor just added is not considered an extension of a larger virtual screen, but rather JRE creates two separate virtual screens (each with (0,0) as the upper left coordinate as indicated by the GraphicsConfiguration associated the list of devices retrieved using getScreenDevices()). Restarting the JRE fixes the problem (i.e., the two screens are now treated as part of a larger virtual screen with separate starting coordinates).

My question is: How do you correctly determine the monitor (GraphicsDevice) instance where a Java Applet is currently displayed under the following circumstances:
    1. The user adds a monitor to his PC/laptop
    2. User drags the browser window running the Applet and repositions it in the new screen. 
    3. Any JDialog or other frames need to open in the new screen, but this can only be done if we can automatically detect the screen instance where the Applet was repositioned.

As mentioned earlier, simply checking the position of the Java Applet against the bounds of the graphics configuration of the various screens does not work, as the bounds all start at (0,0).

I don't want my users or customers to have to kill and restart their Java.exe just because a new monitor was added so that screen instances can be correctly melded by JRE into a single Virtual Screen. Any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you use [`setLocationByPlatform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#setLocationByPlatform-boolean-) on your `JDialog`s?

Comment: You're already determining if another screen was added, correct? What happens if you force the new GraphicsDevice to adjust its resolution? (to the same thing, of course) Does this force the JRE to update the virtual screen?

Comment: Jeffrey: Haven't used setLocationByPlatform(), but it appears to place a new window in the default location for the underlying OS which may not be on the same monitor or screen as where my application is currently placed. Hence the need to determine that explicitly. If there's a trick to using that function, let me know.

Comment: Christopher: While I can detect that a new monitor was added, I am unable to distinguish it's virtual coordinates from the previous monitor as they both start at (0,0). Do you know of a specific function which will force the JRE to re-enumerate the graphics devices and create one larger virtual screen?